# How do I write this with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, tdd, capybara

I upgraded my version of rspec to the most current version and I have tests breaking that have similar syntax

```
it "should delete a company" do
  expect { click_link "Delete Company" }.should change(Company, :count).by(-1)
end
```

I looked at the [documentation](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-11/docs/diffing) and I could not see anything that will do this in the current verion...any ideas on how to achieve this

The error I get is

```
9) Company Pages Edit page as an admin user should delete a company
   Failure/Error: expect { click_link "Delete Company" }.should change(Company, :count).by(-1)
   NoMethodError:
     undefined method `call' for #<RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationTarget:0x007fccafdfc360>
   # ./spec/requests/companies_spec.rb:79:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: shouldnt this be ```to``` instead of ```should``` ?

Comment: Also, if you're going to put your `change` condition on the next line after `to`, make sure to add parenthesis to your `to` or you'll get an error.

Comment: Do you have a approval modal dialog for the delete action? If so, well that's not gonna work neither.

Comment: I can confirm that @phoet is correct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's the [doc](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-0/docs/matchers/expect-change) on using expectations

```
it "should delete a company" do
  expect { click_link "Delete Company" }.to change{Company.count}.by(-1)
end
```

Note the following changes

1. `should` becomes `to`
2. `(Company, :count)` becomes `{Company.count}`